# Spectral Elongation in Hyper Spectral Images

Tags: ai.artificial-intel, cv.computer-vision

I am reading a paper on Denoising Hyper Spectral Images, The paper uses a single model CNN to denoise HSI's, In the paper, before feeding the HSI to the CNN, the paper performs a Spectral Elongation Step to exploit the spatial-spectral correlations between bands of HSI, For this purpose, if let's suppose we have 12 bands in our HSI and we want to denoise the 5th bands, then the paper takes K adjascent bands with it, so if we have 12 bands in total, we want to work on the 5th band and we choose K to be 4, then It will take Band 3,4 and Band 6,7 along with Band 5 as input to the CNN and gives Band 5 as output, the question that I had is that what if we are working on the last band i.e. Band 12, there are no bands to the right of it so how will we choose the adjascent bands then?
Name of the paper : Maffei20_A Single Model CNN for Hyperspectral Image Denoising

Comment: Please give the exact reference of "a paper": it will help to contextualize your question...